# configure error for --- gobject ---- python header not found

Tags: python, gtk, gobject

Python header files are not found when configuring gobject-introspection.

I have downloaded tar for :-----

```
gobject-introspection-1.34.2
```

command :-----

```
gobject-introspection-1.34.2$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./configure --disable-static
```

Error :----

```
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for headers required to compile python extensions... not found
  configure: error: Python headers not found
```

How can i resolve this error, please suggest ?

Comment: You'll need to (correctly) install the python development package. On most OS/Distributions this is one-liner, e.g. `apt-get install python-dev`.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler is looking for Python header files. On a Linux distro this is usually solved via installing `python-dev` or a similar package. Under the hood, you should be able to specify the include directory via gcc's `-I` option.

Comment: python-dev ---> Is it part of python 2.7 source. Actually i want to compile it using configure script for my target ?

Comment: No, `python-dev` is a package in Debian-based operating systems. To specify the headers directory manually (e.g. from Python 2.7 sources), run the configure script e.g. as follows: `./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/python/headers/include_dir"`

Comment: ok this is to configure the package which are dependent on phython ?-----> What if i need to configure, make & make install phython itself for my target, then what i have to do for this ?

Comment: i configured using ------>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./configure --disable-static CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/lib/python2.7"    --------> i added this path ---> /usr/lib/python2.7  ---> this contains many files with .py extention ---> but same error is coming ?

Comment: Python is already installed i have checked ----->does configure looking for .h or .py file  ?

Comment: For `.h` files. `.py` files are Python files, `.h` files are C or C++ header files.

Comment: CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include/python2.7"  even this failed ----> can you suggest one name of python header file --> which i can search using --> find command ---> then i can reach exact directory where headers are ?

Comment: ignite@ignite:~/sbox2/rootfs/rfs-raspbian$ find -type f -name "py*.h" --------------->
./usr/include/python2.6/pygame/pygamedocs.h
./usr/include/python2.6/pygame/pygame.h
./usr/include/python3.2mu/pyconfig.h
./usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h
./usr/include/python2.7/pygame/pygamedocs.h
./usr/include/python2.7/pygame/pygame.h

Comment: I am getting following output as shown above ----> file you mentioned is not there ---> but python is installed ----> python --version Python 2.7.3rc2

Comment: should i download ---> http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.2.3/Python-3.2.3.tar.xz   ----> an configure, make & make install python again ?

Comment: please suggest if -- python is there then why its .h files are not there ?

Comment: @Katoch, no offense, but I am not going to solve your problems of compiling gobject-introspection-1.34.2 because of missing Python headers. You have my answer - install python-dev. If you are not qualified enough, look for help somewhere else, Stackoverflow is about programming, not a bunch of compilation issues.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you've to intall a dev-package for Python like 'python-dev' in Ubuntu or Debian? The command would be

```
aptitude install python-dev
```

Comment: if i want to compile & then make install ... Please suggest what release of phython to use ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution [here](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/configure-configure-error-python-headers-not-found.html)!

> Usually /usr/bin/python should be just a symbolic link to Python3 or
> Python2,
>
> if it is to point to Python3, the we need to remove the link, and then
> create a symbolic link to Python2
>
> `rm /usr/bin/python`
>
> `ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`
>
> This creates a symbolic link for Python2.7, that doesn't need to restart.

Answer (score 0):

on centos when having a standalone version of python-2.7.12 for example in a shared directory notice that python-config is really named python2.7-config

same for python....it is probably called python2.7

personally, to solve building gobject I:

cd'd into the bin directory of python-2.7.12 and created symlinks

ln -s python2.7 python
ln -s python2.7-config python-config

Hope this helps